# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' reason: '[<productDetailsView 0x7c29fa60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, nsunknownkeyexception

I have a problem with Xcode 6 !!

I have a problem at run-time as follows:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<productDetailsView 0x7c29fa60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'
```

App crashes at start:

```
Class STinAppPurchaseMngr.m  ------> STinAppPurchaseMngr: inAppPurchaseManager 

//Called when app start

    -(void)initialize:(STAppDelegate*)delegate {
    [self requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            initialized_ = YES;
        } else {
            STLog(@"<Error> Unable to retrieve in-app purchase product list");
        }

    }];
    self.MyAppDelegate = delegate;

    [[productDetailsView sharedInstance] setMyAppDelegate:self.MyAppDelegate];   //Here I have Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
}


//Class productDetailsView.m ————>productDetailsView : UIView

+(productDetailsView*) sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static productDetailsView * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{                           //Here I have Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];     
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

With Xcode 5 everything works perfectly! Anyone has a  problem like this?
How to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `productDetailsView` actually define a property named `description`?  If so, do you see compile warnings for it?  (Xcode 6 seems to have made using `description` more of a problem than it used to be because of its use in `NSObject`.)  If it exists and you change it and references to it to some other name, it should clear up the issue.

If you don't have a description property **that's** the problem because something (probably in a xib or storyboard) thinks you do.

Comment: Philip thank you!! It was redeclared without readonly property!!!